# Codeigniter: Get array generated in library to use it on view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, ldap

I'm having issue trying to bring an array filled with user information in library to show it in view.

I have this, in the library, here is generated the array.

```
    $filter = $this->login_attribute.'='.$username;
    $filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)({$filter}))";
    $fields = array("cn","samaccountname","mail","memberof","department","givename","sn","usercedula","telephonenumber","phisycaldeliveryofficename");


    $search = ldap_search($this->ldapconn,$this->search_base,$filter,$fields);

    $entries = ldap_get_entries($this->ldapconn, $search);
```

$entries is the array with the user information. ¿How I move the array to view page?

Edit: The function where $entries is, return other value, $entries is use to reach that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to view by doing something likes this:

in controller:

```
$data['entries']=$entries;
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

in library:

```
class library_name
{
    private $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->ci = &get_instance();
    }
    public function your_function(){
        //$entries=...
        $data['entries']=$entries;
        $this->ci->load->view('view_name',$data);
    }
}
```

in view_name:

```
print_r($entries);
```

Comment: It send me an error "Call to a member function view() on a non-object" when I try to send the array: $this->load->view('view_name',$data);

Comment: @AngelJaramillo I just updated my answer. it should work now.

Comment: It worked!The only problem is showing twice the page.

Comment: I fixed the twice page problem modifying this: $this->ci->load->view('view_name',$data); into this: view = $this->ci->load->view("inventario/create",  $infent, TRUE );

Comment: You should not be loading views from a library (unless it is a theme library or output library. You should only load a view as the last thing you do in the controller. By putting TRUE as the third arguement you are simply returning the view as a string with no output generated. This is certainly more normal in a library if you then return that view to the controller to be used as the data for another view.

Answer (score 1):

A library is just a class. You load it:

```
$this->load->library('my_library');
```

Then you can use any functions in that library:

```
$this->my_library->my_function('some_data');
```

If you are expecting any return values you would use them for whatever, in an if statement, to assign to a variable, etc etc.

```
if ($this->my_library->my_function('some_data')) // Expecting a return of TRUE or FALSE

$my_variable = $this->my_library->my_function('some_data');
```

In your library, your function does whatever you need, and simply returns the data, just like any other function.

```
public function my_function($data)
{
     // do some stuff

     // return some results - variable or array or whatever
     return $results;
}
```

Does that help at all? In your case you just need to return $entries.

Comment: The problem is, the function that generates the $entries is used for other validations and return other thing and $entries is left there. I want to take that $entries and use the information inside to display in user's view page.

Comment: That is a bit too abstract to answer. A library is just a class with methods. Each method can only do one thing, but you can have many methods in one class. You send your prerequisites, like user_id to the method called 'get_entries' and it returns your entries, What you do with that after is up to you. Send it to a view, or manipulate in some other way. The method 'get_entries' cannot then be used by something else to do something else. Validation is a whole other story and there is a validation class in CI that helps validate data. There are also models to help with separation of concerns.